# how does depth_multiplier in tensorflow DepthwiseConv2D work?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution, channel, color-depth

Currently I am studying about Computer Vision, and studying about Depthwise Convolution. (Not Depthwise Seperate Convolution!)

So, What I want to know is how does **"depth_multiplier"** argument works.

## First of all,

When not using "depth_multiplier" and only use
**DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size = (3,3)),**
the shape of the kernels are (3x3x3)
and the output shape becomes (32x32x3)

### and here is the question,

But when I am using "depth_multiplier",

**DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size = (3,3),depth_multiplier=4)**

does the shape of the kernel become (3x3x3)x4?   -> which means 4 of (3x3x3) kernels

and the output shape becomes (32x32x3)x4? OR output shape becomes (32x32x12)?

### It is important for me Because

after this layer I am going to use Normal Convolution. which has 128 number of kernels and kernel_size = (3,3). And I want to know **HOW** the shape of the kernel will be. Will it be (3x3x3)x128? OR other shape?

The Code for training works but want to know How It Actually Works.

**ALSO I want to know how (depth_multiplier=#) really works.**

Thank you Previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

With `depth_multiplier=1`:

```
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
y = tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size = (3,3), padding='SAME')(x)
keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y).layers[-1].weights[0].shape

#outputs TensorShape([3, 3, 3, 1])
```

With `depth_multiplier=4`:

```
y = tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size = (3,3),depth_multiplier=4, padding='SAME')(x)
keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y).layers[-1].weights[0].shape

#outputs: TensorShape([3, 3, 3, 4])
```